# Properties of <div> tag inside a <div>

Tags: html, css

Does the properties/style of div class A overlap B in the below case?

```
<div class="A">
   <div class="B">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you describe more what overlap means here.. Some CSS properties are inherited, some are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough but most of the times, properties can 'overlap' or are inherited.
For eg., if we add a text in the div with class 'B' and add a CSS styling for the text to the div with class 'A', you will be able to see that the styling for the text is changed. Although, if you provide styles to the second div also, it would be considered for the styling of the text.

Please provide further context so I can help better.

```css
.A {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    this is a text
  </div>
</div>
```